# как внедрить обнаружение объектов yolov8 в mjpeg-streamer?

Tags: javascript, html

Используя roboflow хочу внедрить в видеопоток обнаружение объектов.

Мой код:

```
<img id="specialist-stream" class="rounded-md flex-none" src="http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream" alt="" style="display: none;">
```

---

```
var bounding_box_colors = {};
var confidence = 0.6;

function drawBoundingBoxes(predictions, img, ctx) {
  for (var i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
    var confidence = predictions[i].confidence;

    if (confidence < user_stated_confidence) {
      continue;
    }

    if (predictions[i].class in bounding_box_colors) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = bounding_box_colors[predictions[i].class];
    } else {
      var o = Math.round,
        r = Math.random,
        s = 255;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      bounding_box_colors[predictions[i].class] = ctx.strokeStyle;
    }

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    var prediction = predictions[i];
    var x = prediction.bbox.x - prediction.bbox.width / 2;
    var y = prediction.bbox.y - prediction.bbox.height / 2;
    var width = prediction.bbox.width;
    var height = prediction.bbox.height;

    var scaling = window.devicePixelRatio;

    ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;
    ctx.lineWidth = "4";
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
    ctx.font = "25px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(prediction.class + " " + Math.round(confidence * 100) + "%", x, y - 10);
  }
}

roboflow.auth({
  publishable_key: "public-key"
}).load({
  model: "model-name",
  version: 4
}).then(function(model) {
  var img = document.getElementById("specialist-stream");

  setInterval(function() {
    // Create a new Image element to load each frame
    var frame = new Image();
    frame.src = img.src; // This will trigger fetching the latest frame

    frame.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      model.detect(canvas).then(function(predictions) {
        var ctx = img.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

        drawBoundingBoxes(predictions, img, ctx);
      });
    };
  }, 1000 / 30);
});
```

Но что-то не полуается, пишет ошибку:

```
gpgpu_util.js:142 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.
```